# Replica distribution between racks using NetworkTopologyStrategy in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

We currently uses NetworkTopologyStrategy with these settings. 
- 1 DataCenter
- 3 racks
- 9 RF (Replication Factor).

What we observed is that sometimes a replica is not evenly distributed among the racks. (rack1: 5, rack2: 2, rack3: 2) The challenge with this that it can't be fault tolerant if rack 1 with 5 replicas goes down.

After checking all the documentation, it all says it "attempts" to even distribute the data across the racks. After looking at the source code, it doesn't suggest that the strategy is trying to evenly distribute the replicas. It only tries to make sure each rack has at least one replica.  I am wondering if there is a setup where we can have more guaranteed about the distribution.  Would there be challenges if we implement our own strategy so that it attempts to evenly distribute the replica?

Another possibility for us is to have 9 racks if we really want to RF 9 but also requires some work on the snitch side. I am looking for suggestions on how to best tackle this if RF 9 is our goal. Thank you.

Comment: How many total nodes in your Cassandra cluster? What is your consistency level?

Comment: I don't see the problem. A replica is a set of data. Having 3 replicas on a rack is 3 complete sets of the same data. Whether it's 1 replica or 5, there's still a complete set of data on each rack. Although maybe this isn't your goal, and I don't understand?  :)